# How can i access and control hardware in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, scada

I try to developing simple **scada system** with C++ in Qt. I want to control hardware or get status(or something) of hardware and send to server or router.(actually my application control softwares too)

And in finish: Qt have a good tools for **scada systems**?

Comment: The question (if it were on topic) should probably be, does c++ have good tools for scada systems?

Comment: almost Qt, but c++ tools for scada my question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of QT 5.7 there is a new Serial Bus library for use with protocols such as CAN BUS and MODBUS, you can read more about it here:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialbus-index.html

For your scenario, QT has plenty of Network support that you could use for your interface, depending on what your hardware specification is.  QT does not compare to 'out of the box' SCADA solutions such as a Siemens SCADA system, however developing one based on QT could give you much more flexibility.  Depending on what you are trying to achieve, this becomes a trade-off between productivity/time to market and flexibility/value add.

Answer (score 0):

Also there is an opensource qt scada toolkit https://github.com/IndeemaSoftware/QSimpleScada, for visualization.